# Inline Horizontal Form in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Airbnb have a neat form on their site that has three controls inline:

[image: AirBNB's Form]

I tried to replicate this, but my form doesn't seem to be shaping up, despite using Bootstrap columns.

My code is

```
<div className="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <Geosuggest
      fixtures={fixtures}
      inputClassName="form-control"
      onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
      onBlur={(value) => this.onBlur(value)}
      onChange={(value) => this.onChange(value)}
      onSuggestSelect={(suggest) => this.onSuggestSelect(suggest)}
      location={new google.maps.LatLng(53.558572, 9.9278215)}
      radius="20"
    />
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <DateRangePicker
      {...this.props}
      onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
      onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
      startDatePlaceholderText='Llegada'
      endDatePlaceholderText='Salida'
      focusedInput={focusedInput}
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      minimumNights={0}
      className="form-control"
    />
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <select className="form-control" id="sel1">
      <option>1 persona</option>
      <option>2 personas</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <button className="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your elements in specific columns, like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-4">Options</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Option 1</option>
                        <option>Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Option 1</option>
                        <option>Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, there's no harm in tweaking these sizes for different viewports, but it is advised when using this sort of `.horizontal-form` to wrap your `.form-control` in a nested `div`, but the `label` on its own.

I'd also advise to add `top: 6px` or so to the label. It makes it align in the center.

Comment: It is still not grouped like the referenced form(airbnb). http://i.imgur.com/QjBDJ1k.png

Comment: Look at the source of their form, it only uses Bootstrap grids, not form styling. You can't replicate that with Bootstrap alone.